# How to print pil image python (hardcopy)?

Tags: python, winapi, printing, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os
img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 30), color = (73, 109, 137))

#fnt = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf', 15)
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
d.text((10,10), "Hello world", fill=(255, 255, 0))
#img.save('pil_text_font.png')
```

I want to print this image on paper. How can I do that?
I tried,

```
os.startfile(img,'print')
```

Error:

```
TypeError: startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not Image
```

Comment: ... write the image into a *file*, then pass the *file name* to `os.startfile`...

Answer (score -1):

Save your image to a file then output to screen like so:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 30), color = (73, 109, 137))

#fnt = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf', 15)
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
d.text((10,10), "Hello world", fill=(255, 255, 0))
img.save('pil_text_font.png')

# open method used to open different extension image file
im = Image.open(r"pil_text_font.png") 
  
# This method will show image in any image viewer 
im.show() 

#delete the file immediately after to save space
os.remove("pil_text_font.png")
```

Here is a link on where I got my information from for this answer: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-image-open-method/

Comment: What's the point of saving to file and then reloading please? You already have a `PIL Image` in `img` surely?

Comment: because `Image.open()` only works on a filepath, I can't give it raw data like `img`, or `d`. If you know how to use Image.open() on raw data then I support you.